# Drawing Using Grease Pencil Hotkeys

Tags: interface, shortcut

I've just begun experimenting with the Grease pencil function. I find it a bit inconvenient that if there are default hotkeys defined, I can't find them. I'd like to be able to press a key or two, and be able to draw, press a different key combination, and be able to erase what I've drawn, and still a different key combinations, and be able to draw in polyline mode.  Does anyone have any key assignments for the grease pencil that they'd care to share with the me and the community?

I'd also like to be able to redefine the cursor for the Grease pencil's erase mode. As it is now, the erase cursor looks almost exactly like the circle select tool cursor: a white circle with a black dot. If we nominated a different color for the erase cursor in grease pencil, what color should we propose?

Answer (score 13):

- Hold <kbd>D</kbd> and press <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to draw
- Hold <kbd>D</kbd> and press <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to erase
- Hold <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and press <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to draw a line
- Hold <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and press <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to draw a poly line

The shortcuts are in the tooltips:

[image]

Also note that the *Circle select* and *Grease pencil erase* circles are already subtly different:

Circle select Grease pencil

[image] [image]

Comment: I saw those shortcuts in the User preferences page. But I'm looking for a purely keyboard shortcut, like "DD" to draw, "DE" to erase, and maybe "DL" to draw a line, parallel to how we can press the "E" key to extrude and the "R" key to rotate. But I'll have to give it more consideration. For one thing, I learned about the Hotkeys after I last used the grease pencil. The difference between the grease pencil and the circle select circles are too subtle, IMO.

Comment: @brasshat What do you mean by a "purely keyboard shotcut"? Without mouse input, how would blender know where to draw the line?

Comment: Well, for some people there's the tablet. <end joke mode> I was thinking of "purely keyboard in terms of selecting which aspects of the grease pencil tool to use. In one set of meshes I currently have in progress, I press the G and the Z key to move vertices along the z axis, and then use the mouse to do the actual movement. But, then again, maybe I just need to practice more with the shortcuts now that I know about them.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying now. You can sort of do that by making the keymap item a keyboard shortcut (e.g. `D`) instead of a mouse action, however it won't release unless you press esc or click.. [screenshot](http://pasteall.org/pic/76078)

Comment: i dont see any shortcuts info in my tooltips in blender 2.78 / linux

Comment: @martin Same here. The grease pencil was refactored recently, perhaps it got lost then. You might want to [report this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports) to the devs

Comment: To draw a line now, press CTRL+D+LMB, then release CTRL. If you won't release the CTRL, you will only be able to draw horizonal or vertical lines (I'm writing it here for my own reference as I often forget about this and fight with being locked to horizonal/vertical lines).