# How to draw grease pencil on a surface (blender 2,75)?

Tags: grease-pencil

I used to draw grease pencil on surface normally on older blender versions but now I cant find the option to do that,how can I draw on surface on the new blender grease pencil?

Comment: FYI, [here's the solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/116579/14306) for Blender 2.8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the toolbar (T) you now have a grease pencil tab. The stroke placement is in that tab.

[image]

Comment: I cant see the option for drawing on the surface !

Comment: click on draw first

Answer (score 16):

Add a new *Grease Pencil* datablock in a properies window (<kbd>N</kbd>). In Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>) change the stroke placement to ***Surface***. Hold  <kbd>D</kbd> and then press and hold the LMB button to draw. Disable the *X Ray* option if you don't want to see the strokes through the object. To erase, hold  <kbd>D</kbd> button and then press and hold the RMB.
[image]

Comment: Maybe useful: D, if I understand correctly, is a shortcut to activate the actual Draw/Erase grease pencil functions. D+LMB is equivalent to pressing Draw in the toolshelf and use mouse to draw, while D+RMB is equivalent to pressing Erase to erase with mouse. Similarly, Ctrl-D activates Line and Poly. The four buttons are grayed while the shortcuts are active as visible on the animation above. More on this [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15330/15265).