# How to easily make mesh retopology?

Tags: modeling, topology

After creating some hi-poly model, i'm always creating low-poly model by approximating that hi-poly mesh with triangle-by-triangle LP mesh - with snap to face mode turned on.

So the process looks like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> (x times), and hitting <kbd>F</kbd> on keyboard, so the new face was made.

Then I'm using this low poly model to texture baking, mainly for gamedev purposes.

This method is very time consuming, so how to make retopology process easier and quicker?

Comment: To reduce the number of tris, there is the "decimation modifier", is it suitable for your workflow?

Comment: Not fully, in my common scenario, I'm using many hipoly meshes / objects (spheres, beveled boxes, some complex ones like i.e. boolean like meshes) that in composition forms a base, for "gluing" or wrapping them with one, low poly mesh.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CMhDjgy2sE try this one using ice tools addon and bsurfaces.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are some wonderful tools for speeding up the retopology process:

- polystrips (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VN1aC7DsS6A)
- contours (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RR06wjt2rs)

These are paid, but worth every penny as they're really time-saving tools.

If you don't want to buy them you may do a fast retopology using a ***Bsurfaces addon***. Go to *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>*-->Add-ons*) and enable it.
[image]

Add an object you want to retopologize, then add a *Plane* (or any other object you like), enter the *Edit Mode* and delete it (<kbd>x</kbd>). In the *Properties Panel* (<kbd>N</kbd>) add a new ***Grease Pencil*** layer, then go to the *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>)*-->Grease Pencil* and change a stroke placement to ***Surface***.
[image]

Now go to the *Tool* bookmark in a *Tool Shelf*. Draw some strokes on an object (hold <kbd>D</kbd>, then press LMB [ [How to draw grease pencil on a surface (blender 2,75)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-to-draw-grease-pencil-on-a-surface-blender-2-75) ]). When finished, click on ***Add Surface*** in Bsurface panel. Change the settings below as you like.
[image]

Comment: I dunno about polystrips and contours. They are not that time saving and the tool is unusable with high poly-counts. I get much more done with just F2 and BSurfaces. Also Topogun is $100 which makes Retopoflow actually really overpriced for it's toolset.

Comment: Yeah, https://cgcookie.com/course/introduction-to-retopoflow/

Comment: According to the Blender Institute, all addons, if they use the Blender API calls, have to be made available compliant to the GNU GPL.  https://www.blender.org/support/faq/  This means that whilst its legal for addons to be sold, its also legal to distribute copies for free.  Retopoflow can be downloaded from https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try Instant Meshes. It's free and depending on your model it might deliver decent results.

It's not like you will get good results with a single click on a button and it also might be unsuitable if you want to have a real low poly count.

Here's a link to the author's github:

[Instant Meshes](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes)

Answer (score 1):

Was just looking myself for this answer...
This might also be useful
Speed retopo a plugin using bsurfaces
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFfqePn8nKI

The authors link - Available on Gumroad.
https://gumroad.com/l/speedretopo

Needs blender 2.78
Activate Bsurface, Looptools and Automirror

you must also install retopo MT & AutoMirror : https://www.dropbox.com/s/cserm65c058yc6h/Retopo_MT.py?dl=0

AutoMirror:
https://framagit.org/Lapineige/Blender_add-ons/tree/master/AutoMirror

[image]

[image: press add b surface or draw directly on mesh using retopo MTand it will place quads down automagically - see video for demo]

[image: Using Retopo MT]
click on the quad where you want to start to draw you can add divisions or delete by pressing X or W and they form to the mesh, Gridfill and other options are available

Comment: why down votes? when this system works way better than standard b-surfaces grease pencil? happy to fix to make it a better answer (since the plugin is great it deserves to be known about)- but just voting down is unhelpful.