# Blender Model goes black only in Edit Mode

Tags: edit-mode

In sculpt mode and object mode the object is normal. However when I enter edit mode the object goes black. I tried removing doubles and recalculating normals but
the model stayed black in edit mode. I have noticed that when I zoom in edit mode, the model has wavy black lines.
[image: Sculpt mode]

[image: Edit mode. Zoomed in you can it has wavy lines.]

Comment: to me, what you see in black here are the vertices : you have more than 230k vertices

Comment: Lemon, so what should I do. I mean I have 230k vertices so does that mean I should remove doubles?

Comment: What should you do for ? Black here is not a color, but an indication of the vertices positions. To me, it seems you tried to use a multiresolution modifier but in fact or you did not, or you did applied it (and probably, that's why you have so many vertices in edit mode now)

Comment: Yeah I did use a multiresolution modifier earlier. I was sculpting and I accidently deleted the modifier so I re-added it. By the way thanks for all the help so far. I also pressed subdivide again.

Comment: ok. I just can say, next time, do not apply the multiresolution, unless you are sure you want to do that. But more than that here, I can't say. You can eventually make a new model by retopo this one if you are happy with its shape.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty happy with its shape. So how would I go about doing a retopo. (I'm new to blender so forgive me for not knowing some of the terminology.)

Comment: With this kind of tools http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36525/how-to-easily-make-mesh-retopology. And the mesh_f2 addon is particularly useful. Find some tutorials about it https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=blender+retopo&tbm=vid. And think about the topology (BTW) as it is a good and very important thing to learn

Comment: A good example for this, get a UV Sphere, subdivide it 10 times, then try again, a couple times. You can see the vertices multiplying.

Comment: Thanks guys. Especially Lemon those were some good links.

Answer (score 2):

Your model has a lot of vertices, and that is perfectly fine.  The black lines indicate edges going between vertices on your model.  The vertices are hard to pick out at this distance, but when you zoom in on your model, the vertices (where the crossroads are) will be a little bit bigger.

Keep in mind that the point of Edit Mode is for you to select/deform/etc. the vertices, so it needs to display them.  While in Sculpt Mode or Object Mode, those vertices are not needed, so they are hidden, instead displaying the material of the object.

You can also look at this like the difference between Object Mode and Rendered Mode.  Both display the model, one using the OpenGL render (default for the 3D viewport), and the other is the Blender Internal render, which takes longer, but still displays your model, with different lighting calculations that give a more realistic result.

Comment: Oh so is this perfectly fine? Its just I'm following a tutorial for character modelling and the person added a multiresolution modifier. Then they took it out to work on the hands.

Comment: @0z00 Yep!  This is completely normal.  If you are planning on using this model in a game however, where you need real time rendering, then it may be too detailed for it to render.  Normal rendering in Blender should be perfectly fine, though the more vertices it needs to render, it will take longer.  I have made models in the past with a couple million vertices, Blender can handle it, though your computer might slow down.

Comment: I've got a high end pc. With a Nvidia GTX 970 so would that still slow it down? And then if I am doing real time rendering is there a way I could cut down the number of veritices the model has. I'm planning on using this model in my game. I'm the UE4 game engine by the way

Comment: @0z00 With more vertices, a computer will always slow down.  More hardware will push where the limit is.  For games, it starts to get complicated to say which way it will go.  I have not used UE4, don't know how many objects are going in your final scene, don't know what types of shaders you are using, target hardware, etc.  You will need to test, and see what works for you.

Comment: Ah i see ok thanks. However i do want to work on the model more in edit mode for the hands. So is there a way I could get rid of the black lines for editing. Sorry for all these questions, you must be feeling quite tired from all of them.

Comment: @0z00 Don't be! Questions are always good, provided you are learning something. You do not want to get rid of the lines and points, as you need to grab them to move/extrude/scale/etc.  If you don't have them, you can't do anything!  There are different modes of selection (vertex, edge, and face) that you can use as well.  If you are looking to just view the model, go for Object Mode, or Rendered Mode.

Comment: @0z00, Gilderman. If I can say : for a game generally around 20k max vertices (for a main character with head, hands, feet). For your prev question above you can try to decimate (modifier) your current mesh (make a copy before) to lower the amount of vertices (a get ride of some of the black lines). But again think about topology because later you'll have to rig it (modify it and so on).

Comment: @lemon I would agree on the 20k max, but I my opinion, there are many different ways that games go, and the character may be the highest detailed model in the scene. I didn't feel comfortable saying that one particular direction was the way to go.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks a lot you've answered all my major queries.

Comment: Yep this is my main character. So I'll go ahead and try out the decimate modifier. Can i ask you any questions about the decimate modifier if i get any problems

Comment: @0z00 If you have issues with the modifier, you may wish to open another question.

Answer (score 0):

You subdivided your mesh a couple of times. Edit mode reveals the mesh of your model. The black lines mark the borders between the faces.

[image: normal and subdivided]

Left - original mesh, right - 3 times subdivided

Comment: Wait so can i un-subdivide my mesh back to the original mesh?