# How to fix the sinking area surface after decimate?

Tags: modifiers

I have a 3D model which I am going to use it in a website but the size of the model is way above acceptable range for online applications. So I tried to decimate the model, but its surface sinks in. how can I fix it!?

#### Original Rendered Model

[image]

#### After Decimating

[image]

Comment: Try using Srkinwrap modifier and point it out to the highpoly. But probably Decimate deleted too much geometry and now the lowpoly is too lowpoly. Then either remodel those areas manually (using Shrinkwrap) or redo the lowpoly

Comment: @MrZak Nope. it didn't work. this happens even when I set deciment ratio to`0.8`! the problem is I want a model with 1.5MB size, become less than 0.5MB and also keep its surface intact, is there any otherway than `deciment` modifier for such purposes?

Comment: Doing retopology is the most common way of that. It can be manual, automated with addons or mixed, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36525/how-to-easily-make-mesh-retopology

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to bake your high-res model to a displacement map which you apply to a low-res mesh afterwards.
I found a video tutorial how to do that:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=l1ASzhU9O-A