# time to decimate & bake a hi poly to low poly model?

Tags: performance

How long does it take to decimate and bake the texture from a hi poly human model (~500K) to low poly model(~20K).

What blender addon do you use for that ?
With or without GPU ?

Thank you
Albert

Comment: I dunno, have you *tried* it?

Comment: How are you going to decimate? With modifier? Manually? What system specs do you have? There are multiple [addons for retopology](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36525/how-to-easily-make-mesh-retopology), each of them more or less depends on your modelling skill level. One answer which could be given to your questions is GPU won't be used neither in baking nor in decimating.