# Question about topology?

Tags: texture-baking, topology

Learning the blender ropes. I wanted to uv unwrap this (attached) high poly mesh to uv paint, but I can't as it's too dense.  The object mainly has texture and creases done with the sculpt tool.

I've been looking up ways to retopologise the mesh but wanted any suggestions of which method is best? Grease paint etc

Also for something like this how 'dense' does the retopo need to be in order to get the texture if that makes sense... and once I've retopoed it do I have to 'bake the normals'?

Many thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Retopology is done in order to provide object with lowpoly geometry which then will take information from highpoly using height and normal maps etc but will be easy to render and maintain (unwrap, edit). There isn't best way to retopo, some general ways are here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36525/how-to-easily-make-mesh-retopology. Once retopo is ready you will bake normals from highpoly to lowpoly.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask as many separate questions as you need.