# Problem with decreasing polygon count

Tags: workflow, faces, subdivision-surface

I am currently working on the gun mesh. I made high poly version and it have 1.6 million faces.

[image]

As I want to publish it online, I need to make low poly. I am not familiar with that workflow, so this is the way i tried to do that:

1. I duplicated high poly part, and got rid of some topology.
2. Then I used decimate modifier (collision), and set the ratio as much as I
   could without deforming mesh. When I use decimate I inevitably get shading
   errors and deformed edges.

[image]

[image]

I have my modifier stack as follows:
-bevel
-subdivision
-decimate
-weighted normal

What is actually the way to do this, and I don’t think of baking normals, but firstly decreasing the poly count of the low poly mesh.
Also, what is generally considered acceptable for games, and is 28000 faces to much?
This really makes me headache, so any advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: You may need to [retopologize](https://conceptartempire.com/retopology/#:~:text=Retopology%20is%20the%20process%20of%20converting%20high-resolution%20models,3D%20artist%20would%20painstakingly%20build%20a%20mesh%20polygon-by-polygon.) the model manually. See if the answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36525/how-to-easily-make-mesh-retopology) can help.

Comment: As far as I know, 28000 faces is a lot, yes. Manual Retopology and baking details into textures is probably the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I thought I could get away with different solution, but retopology is definitely way to go.