# Blender 2.8 greasePencil Poly and surface drawing

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

In the new grease pencil what is the way to stick a surface and where we can find the poly option to create simple block shapes like a typography custom.

Answer (score 5):

When you select a Grease Pencil Object and switch to the **draw mode**, an **Origin** dropdown menu is available at the top right of the window.
You can choose your stroke placement there!

[image: stroke placement in Blender 2.8]

Comment: I don't have a 'draw' mode to my knowledge using 2.8 on OSX

Comment: @ScottAnderson: you have to select a GP object to have it available.